# .NET 8.0 not showing in Visual Studio 2022 (General Release)

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac, .net-8.0

I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio 2022 on my Mac, and I hope someone can help me resolve it. I am unable to use .NET 8, even though I have followed the usual steps for enabling preview features.I cannot find the option to enable .NET 8 preview features in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. The option mentioned in the documentation doesn't appear to be available in my version. If anyone has successfully configured .NET 8 on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac or has insights into resolving this issue, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Are there any additional steps or settings that I might be missing?

Thank you in advance for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZXrB.jpg)

- Updated Visual Studio to the latest version (currently version [Your Visual Studio version]).
- Checked under "Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features," but the option "Use previews of the .NET SDK" is not visible.

  - I have ensured that my Visual Studio is up-to-date.
  - I have checked online resources and documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You are missing a template.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/troubleshooting-no-templates?view=vsmac-2022

Comment: It sounds as though you might be on the preview version and not the stable version. I would try downloading the installer and installing Visual Studio for Mac again, which should install the latest stable version. Updating from a preview version will not switch to the latest stable channel. Download the installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#visual-studio-2022-for-mac

Answer (score 6):

in order to use the .NET 8 SDK with Visual Studio for Mac you have to enable this feature in Preferences - Other - Preview Features - Use the .NET 8 SDK if installed.

Also note that the .NET 8 support in Visual Studio for Mac is still in preview and some things may not work or be fully implemented.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Net-8-not-working-on-VS-for-mac/10516623?ftype=problem&stateGroup=active&sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

From the [What's happening to Visual Studio for Mac?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022) doc:

> Microsoft doesn't plan to add support for .NET 8 or C# 12 to Visual Studio for Mac. We won't extend to any other workloads before retirement either.

You can try using [C# Dev Kit for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/get-started) (or [Rider](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/208074835-Using-Rider-on-Mac-prerequisites)). If you want to still try using Preview Features you might need to install [preview/release candidate](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) version of SDK.